# How to secure mount NFS folder for read & write access?

Tags: security, nfs

I have 4 load balanced apache servers, and all of them can add files to /project/media/ direcotry (different pictures). I want to store all media files in separate server and mount them on apache servers as '/project/media/' NFS folder. How can I do it?

How can I allow only that 4 servers to mount NFS folder? Maybe password or ip filter in NFS settings?

---

All servers are using Ubuntu server 12.04

Answer (score 1):

You specify which hosts may access a share when configuring the exports. Its right there in [man exports](http://linux.die.net/man/5/exports) (here i use an example `webserver[1-4]`, but you can put the IP:s there if you'd like):

```
/project/media/        webserver[1-4](rw)
```

Then how to start the nfs services varies, and since you did'nt specify what server your were planning to use, it's kinda hard to answer.